# Accessing a struct value that's inside of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

First of all, here's my code :

```
    struct eleve
    {
        public string nom;
        public string prenom;
        public char sexe;
        public int programme;
        public naissance datenaissance;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        eleve[] classe = new eleve[8];
        var sexe1 = "MF";
        var random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < classe.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Veuillez ecrire le prenom de l'etudiant.");
            classe[i].prenom = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Veuillez ecrire le nom de l'etudiant.");
            classe[i].nom = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Veuillez ecrire la date de naissance de l'etudiant. (Annee, mois, jour)");
            classe[i].datenaissance.annee = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            classe[i].datenaissance.mois = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            classe[i].datenaissance.jour = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            classe[i].sexe = sexe1[random.Next(sexe1.Length)];
            classe[i].programme = random.Next(1, 400);
        }

        Array.Sort(classe, (x, y) => String.Compare(x.nom, y.nom)); //trie de nom
        for (int i = 0; i< classe.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            affichestruct(classe[i]);
        }
```

I'm trying to create a program that will print out the female and male students seperately, for example, it will show something like this at the end :

```
Male : 
malestudent1
malestuden2

Female : 
femalestudent1
femalestudent2
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't work

```
    static void affichemale(int[] arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Male : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].sexe == "M")
            {
             Console.WriteLine(arr[i].nom);
            }
        }
       Console.WriteLine("Female: ");
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].sexe == "F")
            {
             Console.WriteLine(arr[i].nom);
            }
        }
    }
```

What can I do or change to make it work?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: How exactly does that not work. From what I see that might cause a compiler error...

Comment: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'nom' and no extension method 'nom' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found. I get this message when I try to run it

Comment: Read [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/92369/5056) and understand why you are using `struct` inappropriately here.

Comment: @spender Thank you for the link, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay there are various problems I see. I will list them according to their order in code.

1) Try not to use a struct. Use a class instead if you do not have specific reason for using a struct. More on classes and structs can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

2) You try to call `affichestruct`. This method does not exist and I guess you meant to name `affichemale` differently.

2) `affichemale` gets an `int[]` as a parameter. However you use it as if you actually expected an `eleve[]`. Change the type of the parameter to `eleve[]`. This is why you get the compiler error.

3) In `affichemale` you try to compare "F" and "M" to `eleve.nom`. The problem is  that "M" and "F" are strings and `eleve.nom` is a char. I'm not sure whether this works but I would guess it crashes because of incomparable types. Use 'M' and 'F' for comparison instead.